# Displaying one version of webpage in SERP's based on screen resolution

Tags: css, mobile, resolution, screen-size, desktop

For each page on my site with a mobile equivalent, I use the following HTML tag on the desktop version:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="(mobile)" media="only screen and (max-width:500px)">
```

and I use the following HTML tag on the mobile version of the same page:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="(desktop)" media="only screen and (min-width:720px)"/>
```

In my real pages, I replace (mobile) and (desktop) with the URLs to the mobile version and desktop version of the same page. From my observations, google appreciates this.

I use an 800x600 laptop screen resolution when working on my site, and when I searched for my site with the query "site:example.com" in google, it shows me both the desktop AND mobile version of the homepage.

Since I specified media values, I would think that google would only show the desktop version of my page since my screen resolution is greater than 720 pixels.

Maybe I'm just formatting my tags wrong? I'm not sure. But seeing that 99% of the people now have javascript active in their web browsers, would there be a way for me to make an official declaration to google that I only want certain pages to appear in search results if a user is using a specific screen resolution that falls within the range of resolutions I allow?

I ask because my mobile site for a desktop user would look a bit funny and my desktop site for a mobile user would look awkward since they would have to scroll all over to read paragraphs of text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have mobile redirects implemented?   Google expects sites with separate URLs for mobile and desktop to redirect between them based on user-agent.

Comment: Of course I do. A guest is redirected right away to the mobile equivalent URL advertised in the link tag if the guest's user agent is within the list of known mobile devices and the guest hasn't indicated (via an option on the site) he specifically wants to see the desktop version of the site on the mobile device.